# Django: Get model from string?

Tags: django, django-models

In Django, you can specify relationships like:

```
author = ForeignKey('Person')
```

And then internally it has to convert the string "Person" into the model `Person`.

Where's the function that does this? I want to use it, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 178, accepted):

`django.db.models.loading` was [deprecated in Django 1.7](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.7/django/db/models/loading.py) ([removed in 1.9](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/releases/1.9/#features-removed-in-1-9)) in favor of the the new [application loading system](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/applications/#initialization-process).

Django [1.7 docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/applications/#django.apps.apps.get_model) give us the following instead:

```
>>> from django.apps import apps
>>> User = apps.get_model(app_label='auth', model_name='User')
>>> print(User)
<class 'django.contrib.auth.models.User'>
```

Comment: I used to use pydoc's "locate" function...not sure of the difference here, but in order to stay within Django i've switch to this method.  Thanks.

Comment: optional form `apps.get_model("appName.ModelName")`

Answer (score 202):

> As of Django [1.11](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.get_model) to [4.0](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.get_model) (at least), it's [`AppConfig.get_model(model_name, require_ready=True)`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.get_model)

> As of Django 1.9 the method is [`django.apps.AppConfig.get_model(model_name)`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.get_model).
> -- [danihp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4881607/django-get-model-from-string/4881693?noredirect=1#comment61074369_4881693)

> As of Django 1.7 the `django.db.models.loading` is deprecated (to be removed in 1.9) in favor of the the new application loading system.
> -- [Scott Woodall](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26126935/65387)

---

Found it. It's defined here:

```
from django.db.models.loading import get_model
```

Defined as:

```
def get_model(self, app_label, model_name, seed_cache=True):
```

Comment: This solution is deprecated in Django 1.7, see this other answer for the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26126935/155987

Comment: Hi @mpen, I suggest to you to update your answer. [On django 1.9 get_model is defined on AppConfig](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.get_model): `from django.apps import AppConfig`

Comment: django.apps.AppConfig is a generator type that can not work like model object.

Comment: In Django 1.7+ it is better to use get_model() on the Django app registry, which is available via `django.apps.apps.get_model(model_name)`. AppConfig objects are intended for a different purpose, and require you to create an AppConfig instance in order to call `get_model()`.

Comment: Django 1.11 needs the answer provided by @luke_aus

Comment: as for Django 2.2 its from factory.django import get_model

Comment: @DorZ Isn't that for `factory_boy`? Is factory boy part of Django core?

Comment: Latest (2020) solution: `from django.apps import apps` then: `apps.get_model('app_name', 'Model')`
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38443628/import-error-cannot-import-name-get-model

Comment: 2022: from `django.apps import apps` then: `apps.get_model('app_name.model_name')` also works

Answer (score 89):

just for anyone getting stuck (like I did):

```
from django.apps import apps

model = apps.get_model('app_name', 'model_name')
```

`app_name` should be listed using quotes, as should `model_name` (i.e. don't try to import it)

`get_model` accepts lower case or upper case 'model_name'

Answer (score 34):

Most model "strings" appear as the form "appname.modelname" so you might want to use this variation on get_model

```
from django.db.models.loading import get_model

your_model = get_model ( *your_string.split('.',1) )
```

The part of the django code that usually turns such strings into a model is a little more complex This from `django/db/models/fields/related.py`:

```
    try:
        app_label, model_name = relation.split(".")
    except ValueError:
        # If we can't split, assume a model in current app
        app_label = cls._meta.app_label
        model_name = relation
    except AttributeError:
        # If it doesn't have a split it's actually a model class
        app_label = relation._meta.app_label
        model_name = relation._meta.object_name

# Try to look up the related model, and if it's already loaded resolve the
# string right away. If get_model returns None, it means that the related
# model isn't loaded yet, so we need to pend the relation until the class
# is prepared.
model = get_model(app_label, model_name,
                  seed_cache=False, only_installed=False)
```

To me, this appears to be an good case for splitting this out into a single function in the core code. However, if you know your strings are in "App.Model" format, the two liner above will work.

Comment: I think the 2nd line should be: `your_model = get_model(*your_string.rsplit('.', 1))`. App label sometimes is dotted format, however model name is always a valid identifier.

Comment: Looks like this isn't necessary in the new `apps.get_model`. "As a shortcut, this method also accepts a single argument in the form `app_label.model_name`."

Answer (score 23):

2020 solution:

```
from django.apps import apps

apps.get_model('app_name', 'Model')
```

per your eg:

```
apps.get_model('people', 'Person')
```

per:
[Import Error :cannot import name get_model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38443628/import-error-cannot-import-name-get-model)

Answer (score 19):

The blessed way to do this in Django 1.7+ is:

```python
import django
model_cls = django.apps.apps.get_model('app_name', 'model_name')
```

So, in the canonical example of all framework tutorials:

```python
import django
entry_cls = django.apps.apps.get_model('blog', 'entry')  # Case insensitive
```

Answer (score 15):

In case you don't know in which app your model exists, you can search it this way:

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType 
ct = ContentType.objects.get(model='your_model_name') 
model = ct.model_class()
```

Remember that your_model_name must be lowercase.

Answer (score 9):

Another rendition with less code for the lazy. Tested in Django 2+

```
from django.apps import apps
model = apps.get_model("appname.ModelName") # e.g "accounts.User"
```

Comment: great answer, btw, the string doesn't need to be capitalised, `appname.modelname` also works.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure where it's done in Django, but you could do this.

Mapping the class name to the string via reflection.

```
classes = [Person,Child,Parent]
def find_class(name):
 for clls in classes:
  if clls.__class__.__name__ == name:
   return clls
```

Comment: Is it clls.__class__.__name__ or just clls.__name__?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a less django-specific approach to get a class from string:

```
mymodels = ['ModelA', 'ModelB']
model_list = __import__('<appname>.models', fromlist=mymodels)
model_a = getattr(model_list, 'ModelA')
```

or you can use importlib as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10773699):

```
import importlib
myapp_models = importlib.import_module('<appname>.models')
model_a = getattr(myapp_models, 'ModelA')
```