# Get python class object from string

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dynamic module import in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301134/dynamic-module-import-in-python)

Probably a simple question! I need to iterate through a list of classes (as strings) passed from a settings file. The classes are listed like below:

```
TWO_FACTOR_BACKENDS = (
    'id.backends.AllowToBeDisabled', # Disable this to enforce Two Factor Authentication
    'id.backends.TOTPBackend',
    'id.backends.HOTPBackend',
    #'id.backends.YubikeyBackend',
    #'id.backends.OneTimePadBackend',
    #'id.backends.EmailBackend',
)
```

I now need to call the `authenticate()` function on each of these classes (unless commented out, of course). I'm happily iterating through the list, I just need to know how to convert the strings to a Class object in my foreach loop so that I can call the `authenticate` method on it. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Do you want `authenticate()` called on the classes, or on objects of those classes?

Comment: Sorry, `authenticate()` is called on the classes, not the objects of the classes. Should have made that more clear sorry!

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You want to use [the `importlib` module](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/importlib.html) to handle loading of modules like this, then simply use [`getattr()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#getattr) to get the classes.

For example, say I have a module, `somemodule.py` which contains the class `Test`:

```
import importlib

cls = "somemodule.Test"
module_name, class_name = cls.split(".")

somemodule = importlib.import_module(module_name)

print(getattr(somemodule, class_name))
```

Gives me:

```
<class 'somemodule.Test'>
```

It's trivial to add in things like packages:

```
cls = "test.somemodule.Test"
module_name, class_name = cls.rsplit(".", 1)

somemodule = importlib.import_module(module_name)
```

And it will not import a module/package if it's already been imported, so you can happily do this without keeping track of loading modules:

```
import importlib

TWO_FACTOR_BACKENDS = (
    'id.backends.AllowToBeDisabled', # Disable this to enforce Two Factor Authentication
    'id.backends.TOTPBackend',
    'id.backends.HOTPBackend',
    #'id.backends.YubikeyBackend',
    #'id.backends.OneTimePadBackend',
    #'id.backends.EmailBackend',
)

backends = [getattr(importlib.import_module(mod), cls) for (mod, cls) in (backend.rsplit(".", 1) for backend in TWO_FACTOR_BACKENDS)]
```