# How to parse a pydantic model with a field of type "Type" from json?

Tags: python, pydantic

How to make the following work with pydantic?

```py
from typing import Type

import pydantic


class InputField(pydantic.BaseModel):
    name: str
    type: Type

InputField.parse_raw('{"name": "myfancyfield", "type": "str"}')
```

It fails with

```
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for InputField
type
  a class is expected (type=type_error.class)
```

But I need to parse this from json, so I don't have the option to directly pass the Type object to the `__init__` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A custom [validator](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/validators/) with `pre=True` will allow you to attempt to find a class with the provided name. Here is a working example first trying to grab a built-in and failing that assuming the class is in global namespace:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator


class InputField(BaseModel):
    name: str
    type_: type

    @validator("type_", pre=True)
    def parse_cls(cls, value: object) -> type:
        name = str(value)
        try:
            obj = getattr(__builtins__, name)
        except AttributeError:
            try:
                obj = globals()[name]
            except KeyError:
                raise ValueError(f"{value} is not a valid name")
        if not isinstance(obj, type):
            raise TypeError(f"{value} is not a class")
        return obj


class Foo:
    pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(InputField.parse_raw('{"name": "a", "type_": "str"}'))
    print(InputField.parse_raw('{"name": "b", "type_": "Foo"}'))
```

Output:

```
name='a' type_=<class 'str'>
name='b' type_=<class '__main__.Foo'>
```

If you want to support dynamic imports as well, that is possible too. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10773348) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301134) for pointers.

Comment: Thanks, that looks like a solid solution. I hoped for one without own validation code, but probably it is the best one can do.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert a Pydantic object/type to another Pydantic object/type.

### my-test.py test script

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field


# Some hypothetical Pydantics types.
class PyDanticTypeA(BaseModel):
    attribute_a: str
    attribute_b: str


class PyDanticTypeB(PyDanticTypeA):
    attribute_c: str


class PyDanticTypeC(PyDanticTypeA):
    attribute_d: str = Field("d")


# Converting (parsing) one Pydantic type to another.
pydantic_type_b = PyDanticTypeB(attribute_a="a", attribute_b="b", attribute_c="c")
pydantic_type_c = PyDanticTypeC.parse_obj(pydantic_type_b)

# Testing the converted (parsed) Pydantic type.
print(pydantic_type_c.attribute_d)
pydantic_type_c.attribute_d = "e"
print(pydantic_type_c.attribute_d)
```

### Running my-test.py

```
(my-test) [who-i-am@who-i-am-pc my-test]$ python my-test.py 
d
e
```

Thanks!

✌️

Comment: Where did the attribute_d="d" value come from?  Neither of the two objects have that defined.

Comment: @TristanPerotti I believe you misunderstood the example. Anyway, I improved the example to make it easier to understand. ✌️