# How to get a model object using model name string in Django

Tags: django, django-views

Desciption:

I have a generic function

```
def gen(model_name,model_type): 
      objects = model_name.objects.all()
      for object in objects:
          object.model_type = Null      (Or some activity)
          object.save()
```

How Can I achieve the above ? Is it possible?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I would use `get_model`:

```
from django.db.models import get_model

mymodel = get_model('some_app', 'SomeModel')
```

Comment: Hi. I get an error that says `Cannot import name get_model` in the first line. Did anything change in the latest Django version?

Comment: @Y2H yes, look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4881607/django-get-model-from-string

Answer (score 26):

As of Django 1.7 the `django.db.models.loading` [is deprecated](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.7/django/db/models/loading.py) (to be removed in 1.9) in favor of the the new application loading system. The [1.7 docs give us](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.get_model) the following instead:

```
$ python manage.py shell
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar  5 2014, 10:59:47)
>>> from django.apps import apps
>>> User = apps.get_model(app_label='auth', model_name='User')
>>> print User
<class 'django.contrib.auth.models.User'>
>>>
```

Answer (score 4):

if you pass in 'app_label.model_name' you could use [contenttypes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#module-django.contrib.contenttypes) e.g.

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

model_type = ContentType.objects.get(app_label=app_label, model=model_name)
objects = model_type.model_class().objects.all()
```

Answer (score 0):

The full answer for Django 1.5 is:

```
from django.db.models.loading import AppCache

app_cache = AppCache()
model_class = app_cache.get_model(*'myapp.MyModel'.split('.',1))
```