# How to use variables for models in get_object_or_404 or objects.get

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

In Django, how do I use variables to dynamically use the get_object_or_404 or objects.get like

```
get_object_or_404(${Variable}, pk=id)
```

or

```
${Variable}.objects.get(pk=id)
```

Comment: Python is not PHP. Exactly what is "Variable"? Where's it coming from?

Comment: Variable is just contain a string for the name of the model, so if Variable="ModelA", how can I access ModelA?

Comment: Actually I am trying to ask the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12279846/how-to-get-a-model-object-using-model-name-string-in-django

Answer (score 0):

No problem, assume that you have two models `Post` and `Comment`, You can have this:

```
from app import models as app_models

dynamic_object = getattr(app_models, 'post')
```

So you can use it:

```
dynamic_object.objects.get(pk=id)
```

or

```
get_object_or_404(dynamic_object, pk=id)
```

Comment: what if i have like 30 models? If there any way to get objects by name or from string?

Answer (score 0):

If you assure to pass a **Django ORM Model Class** in the parameter, get_object_or_404() will work just fine.

```
def do_something(id,MyDjangoModelObject = None)
    if MyDjangoModelObject:
        get_object_or_404(MyDjangoModelObject, pk=id)
```

also

```
MyDjangoModelObject.objects.get(pk=id)
```