# why we need to use `get_model` in django?

Tags: python

i saw a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12279846/how-to-get-a-model-object-using-model-name-string-in-django#)

i wonder why i need to use `get_model` ?

i think we can use like this

```
from my_project.my_app.models import model_name

def gen(): 
      objects = model_name.objects.all()
      for object in objects:
          object.model_type = Null      (Or some activity)
          object.save()
```

is there has different?(performence or etc..) if this way have some problem please tell me some advice for me.

thank you :)

Comment: because we need avoid to circular imports [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4379042/django-circular-model-import-issue)