# Django: How to set up a single view for multiple urls where each url points to subclass of a base model?

Tags: django

I have the following urls:

browse/college
browse/department
browse/subjects

I have Tag model where College, Department and Subject are all subclasses on Tag. All the urls will call a single view.

I want to create a view called  browse_specfic_tag(request, model_name)

I was thinking of converting model name to model using [get_model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4881607/django-get-model-from-string) and do something like,

```
TagModel = get_model(model_name..)
```

but I am going to tie url name with model which might not be a good thing to do if I decided to rename either of them.

Any better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> import this
The Zen of Python, by Tim Peters

Beautiful is better than ugly.
Explicit is better than implicit.
…
```

The proper way of solving this is passing an extra option to the view. See [related documentation entry](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#passing-extra-options-to-view-functions).

Example:

```
url('^college/$', 'tag_view', {'model': College})

def tag_view(request, model):
    records = model.objects.filter(…)
```

Furthermore, actions should not be included in URL's name. URLs should identify resources. Therefore I would skip the `browse` part of the URL.