# How to Lazy Load a model in a managers to stop circular imports?

Tags: python, django, django-models

In Django you can create managers for your models. I do this by added a new file called `managers.py` and in my model `objects = MyManager()`.

To stop circular imports I do `self.model`. However, if I need to reference a different model in my manager i.e.

```
from models import SecondModel
second= SecondModel(name=test).save()
self.model(second=second)
```

I get the following error: `ImportError: cannot import name SecondModel`

So is there a way in Django to lazy load a model?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have a few options:

### 1. Import by name

Django has a utility function for importing by string name so you don't need to import yourself. There are several methods available for this (see this question: [Django: Get model from string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4881607/django-get-model-from-string))

```
from django.db.models.loading import get_model

class SomeModelManager(...):
    ...

    def some_function(self):
        model = get_model('your_app', 'YourModel')
        object = model()
```

### 2. Imports at the bottom

Add the import at the bottom of the `managers.py` file and make sure to simply import the module and not the models themselves.

So...

`models.py`:

```
import managers

class SomeModel(models.Model):
    ...
    objects = managers.SomeModelManager()
```

`managers.py`

```
class SomeModelManager(...):
    ...

    def some_function(self):
        object = models.SomeOtherModel()

import models
```

Comment: does Django not have a lazy import? I was always told that imports at the bottom of the page were bad!

Comment: @OrbiterFleet: true, I've added that as an alternative option :)

Answer (score 38):

The currently accepted answer is deprecated as of Django 1.7; from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4881607/django-get-model-from-string/26126935#26126935), you can adapt your code like this.

```
from django.apps import apps

class SomeModelManager(...):
    ...

    def some_function(self):
        model = apps.get_model(app_label='your_app', model_name='YourModel')
```

Comment: How do I import enum object which contain choices from models?

Comment: @МихаилПавлов put the choices in the model class.

Comment: How can I do this with typechecking if `some_function` returns an instance of `YourModel`? i.e. `def some_function(self) -> YourModel:`