# How to access related model in Django custom model manager?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have three models as follows,
`models.py`:

```
class Activity(models.Model):
    # ...

    objects = models.Manager()
    activity = ActivityManager()

    kind = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=KIND_CHOICES)

    # ...

class ActivtyA(models.Model):
    # ...

    activity = models.OneToOneField(
        Activity,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='A',
    )

    # ...

class ActivtyB(models.Model):
    # ...

    activity = models.OneToOneField(
        Activity,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='B',
    )

    # ...
```

and a model manager,
`managers.py`:

```
class ActivityManager(models.Manager):
    def create_activity(self, validated_data):
        # ...

        data = validated_data.pop(kind)
        act = self.create(**validated_data)
        if act.kind == 'A':
            # Create ActivityA(act, **data)
        elif act.kind == 'B':
            # Create ActivityB(act, **data)

         # ... 
    # ...
```

In model manager's `create_activity` method I wand to create `Activty` and either `ActivityA` or `ActivtyB` based on `Activity.kind`. If I import these classes in manager then it results in *circular import error*.
**How can I access `ActivityA` and `ActivtyB` in manager?**

I tried to do this by using signals but couldn't make it.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Activity)
def create_activity_details(sender, instance, using, **kwargs):
    if instance.kind == 'A':
        ActivityA.objects.create(activity=instance, data=????) # Need data to create this object
    elif instance.kind == 'A':
        ActivityB.objects.create(activity=instance, data=????)
```

Comment: What is the exact issue in your `ActivityManager` example? Would that be the circular import mentioned in your answer?

Comment: @djvg; Yes, it is. I added it to the question.

Comment: Could you prevent these import issues by defining the manager in your `models.py`? Or do you really want it in a separate `managers.py` module?

Comment: @djvg; The purpose of this manager is to separate business logic from views and serializers and at the same time avoid making models fat. So, yes it need to be in a separate file.

Comment: This import trick looks promising: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29744414/ (using `django.db.models.loading.get_model`)

Comment: or this seems more up to date: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4881693

Comment: @djvg, Interesting! Thanks for the link. I got it now.

Answer (score 1):

So, I went old school and did this to make it work,

```
data = validated_data.pop(kind)
act = self.create(**validated_data)
if act.kind == 'A':
    from activity.models import ActivityA  # Prevent the circular import
    ActivityA.objects.create(activity=act, **data)
elif act.kind == 'B':
    from activity.models import ActivityB
    ActivityB.objects.create(activity=act, **data)
```

It works, but doesn't look clean. Any better solution other?

---

#### Update:

So, using [`django.apps.apps.get_model`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/applications/#django.apps.apps.get_model) is the answer. Thanks [@djvj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4720018/djvg) for pointing me in the right direction.
Doc says that:

> `apps.get_model(app_label, model_name, require_ready=True)`
> Returns the Model with the given `app_label` and `model_name`. As a shortcut, this method also accepts a single argument in the form `app_label.model_name`. `model_name` is case-insensitive.

Example:

```
from django.apps import apps

class ActivityManager(models.Manager):
def create_activity(self, validated_data):
    # ...

    data = validated_data.pop(kind)
    act = self.create(**validated_data)
    if act.kind == 'A':
        model = apps.get_model(app_label='activity', model_name='ActivityA')
        model.objects.create(activity=act, **data)
    elif act.kind == 'B':
        model = apps.get_model(app_label='activity', model_name='ActivityB')
        model.objects.create(activity=act, **data)

     # ... 
# ...
```

`apps.get_model(app_label='activity', model_name='ActivityA')` can be simply written as

```
apps.get_model('activity.ActivityA')
```