# How to dynamically validate data in django models

Tags: python, django

I have 10 model classes and I wanted to check whether the passed data is available in table or not. I've a plan in mind that I can create a function which will take arguments of modelclass name, attribute to check and value of that field. 
from data import models

```
def IsAvailable(model, attr, val):
  # Here I wanted to create object of given model class and validate whether the attr has the give value.
  obj = getattr(models, model)
  res = obj.objects.get(attr=val)
  return res
```

This will not work because `attr` is not a field in the given model. Can somebody help me here ?

Answer (score 3):

You probably want [`**` keyword pass-through](https://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#id15):

```
def IsAvailable(model, attr, val):
    obj = getattr(models, model)        
    res = obj.objects.get(**{attr: val})
    return res
```

This passes the dictionary `{attr: val}` as keyword arguments to `get()`, i.e. `{'foo': 'bar'}` calls `get(foo='bar'}`.

Bonus points for making this generic:

```
def IsAvailable(model, **kwargs):
    obj = getattr(models, model)        
    res = obj.objects.get(**kwargs)
    return res
```

This lets you call `IsAvailable(model, attr1=val1, attr2=val2)`, testing the availabilty of *all* attributes which might even be more convenient.

In Django 1.7 you can also resolve the model by name for the whole project across applications (also possible in django < 1.7, but using [a different method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4881607/django-get-model-from-string/26126935#answer-4881693)).

```
from django.apps import apps

def get_model_dotted(dotted_model_name):
    app_label, model_name = dotted_model_name.split(".", 1)
    return apps.get_model(app_label, model_name)

def IsAvailable(model, **kwargs):
    model = get_model_dotted(model_name)
    res = model.objects.get(**kwargs)
    return res;
```

Use as `IsAvailable('app1.model1', attr1=value1)`.

Remember that `get()` raises [`MultipleObjectsReturned`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/exceptions/#django.core.exceptions.MultipleObjectsReturned) when more than one object matches the filter, so you might actually want

```
res = model.objects.filter(**kwargs)
```

or even only

```
return model.objects.filter(**kwargs).exists()
```