# Django multiple queryset and concatenation

Tags: angularjs, django, django-models, concatenation, django-queryset

I am building an **advance search** in django/angular where user can select one or more **fields** from different **models**

```
#############               #############           #############
Model1                      Model2                  Model2
#############               #############           #############   
Field1                      Field1                  Field1
Field2                      Field2                  Field2
Field3                      Field3                  Field3
......                      Fk(Model1)              Fk(Model1)
                            .......                 ..........
```

**Model2**, **Model3** and other models have **foreignkey** reference to **Model1**.

The selected models fields are send to the django views for further queries and result concatenation.

**views.py**

```
def customsearch(request):
    queryrequest = json.loads(request.body)

    result = []
    print queryrequest
    """ [{u'value': u'Field1', u'key': u'Model1'}, {u'value': u'Field2', u'key': u'Model2'}, {u'value': u'Field3', u'key': u'Model2'}, {u'value': u'Field2', u'key': u'Field2'}]"""

    for item in queryrequest:
        if(item['key'] == 'Model1'):
            result.append(Model1.objects.filter().values(item['value']))
        else:
            result.append(item['key'].objects.filter().values(item['value']).select_related('fk'))
```

I have got a **request** of  list of dictionaries. The list consist of **key** (model name) and **value** (field).

How can i make a queries and contenate results based on above example?

I am newbie to django!

Any helps and suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

if your model2, model3 has fk to model1,

this is sample (you should use related_name for Model2, Model3 ForeignKey Field)

```
from django.db.models import Q
Model1.objects.filter(
    Q(Field1=value1) & 
    Q(model2_related_name__Field2=value2) &
    Q(model3_related_name__Field3=value3)
)
```

and, about related_name [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#be-careful-with-related-name)

Comment: Can I `Model1.objects.filter()`? And i don't want to match field with value instead get all results. I have edited `views`.

Comment: if you want get all results, not filter(), use all().

Comment: and i cannot understand waht you want this code.      result.append(item['key'].objects.filter().values(item['value']).select_related('fk'))'

Comment: and if you want to get Model Class by string. see this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4881607/django-get-model-from-string)