# Import Error :cannot import name get_model

Tags: python, django, file, picker

```
File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\file_picker\forms.py,line 5 in <module>
from django.db.models import Q,get_model
ImportError:cannot import name get_model
```

I am using  django 1.9.7 and file_picker 0.2.2 I don't seem to have any solution  to this problem

Comment: get_model is discontinued from Django 1.9 onwards.

Comment: It still didn't work I'm confused I'm trying to add widgets to the blog content for styling the admins input to be displayed on the blog site

Comment: What exactly is it that you want to do with get_model?

Answer (score 9):

Try using `django.apps` instead:

```
from django.apps import apps

apps.get_model('Model')
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.get_model

Comment: Only apps.models('Model') works for me     @ Django 3.0.5

Comment: I had to use `apps.get_model('app_name', 'Model')`

Comment: This answer is using `django.apps.apps.get_model` but providing link to `django.apps.AppConfig.get_model` which is quite confusing. Another important point is that `AppConfig.get_model` needs only one argument but [`apps.get_model`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/applications/#django.apps.apps.get_model) needs two. That being said, `apps.get_model('Model')` will not work.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
from django.apps import apps

model_obj = get_model('app_name', 'model_name')
```

Where "app_name" is your app name and "model_name" is your model name.