# Tests failling after django and python upgrade

Tags: python-3.x, django

I've upgraded Django from 4.0.5 to 4.1.6 and python from 3.9 to 3.11

I've also upgraded dependencies:

```
   pip==23.0
   pytest==7.2.1
   pytest-django==4.5.2
   coverage==7.1.0
   pytest-cov==4.0.0
   pylint==2.16.2
   mock==5.0.1
```

These are my logs:

```
django-admin test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/django-admin", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute_from_command_line())
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 440, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 24, in run_from_argv
    super().run_from_argv(argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 394, in run_from_argv
    parser = self.create_parser(argv[0], argv[1])
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 357, in create_parser
    self.add_arguments(parser)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 54, in add_arguments
    test_runner_class = get_runner(settings, self.test_runner)
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/test/utils.py", line 394, in get_runner
    test_module = __import__(test_module_name, {}, {}, test_path[-1])
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django_coverage/coverage_runner.py", line 31, in <module>
    from django.db.models import get_app, get_apps
ImportError: cannot import name 'get_app' from 'django.db.models' (/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/__init__.py)
```

Answer (score 0):

It works with

```
from django.apps import apps
```

[Import Error :cannot import name get_model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38443628/import-error-cannot-import-name-get-model)

But I have other issues with this library which is very old and I removed it from my project.
Ex:

```
django-admin test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/django-admin", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute_from_command_line())
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 440, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 24, in run_from_argv
    super().run_from_argv(argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 394, in run_from_argv
    parser = self.create_parser(argv[0], argv[1])
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 357, in create_parser
    self.add_arguments(parser)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 54, in add_arguments
    test_runner_class = get_runner(settings, self.test_runner)
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/test/utils.py", line 394, in get_runner
    test_module = __import__(test_module_name, {}, {}, test_path[-1])
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django_coverage/coverage_runner.py", line 37, in <module>
    from django_coverage.utils.coverage_report import html_report
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django_coverage/utils/coverage_report/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from html_report import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'html_report'
```