# I was trying to use apps.get_model function. And, I want to use this without specifying the app name, is there any way to do that.

Tags: django, django-models

I was referring this link : [Django: Get model from string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4881607/django-get-model-from-string/26126935)
. And, I found there is a way to do this by using apps.get_model. But,In my scenario, the model can be from other apps. So, I can't actually name the app_name here. Is there any way to do this ?

Comment: This isn't clear. A model can only be from one app. Why can't you specify the app?

Comment: I can't specify the app name bcoz, the model name is a dynamic, and gets from the url. It can come from any app.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) good questions. Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't care which app the model comes from, you can do it the following way:

```
from django.apps import apps

def get_model_from_any_app(model_name):

    for app_config in apps.get_app_configs():
        try:
            model = app_config.get_model(model_name)
            return model
        except LookupError:
            pass

model = get_model_from_any_app('SomeModelName')
```

But in Django models in different apps can have the same name, i.e. your project can have model `Post` in your `blog` app and model `Post` in your `news` app etc.

So this way you can end up with not the model you expect, if they have duplicate names across apps (i.e. you probably should not do it this way, just think why in the world would you want a semi-random model?).

Docs which explain the code:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/applications/#django.apps.apps.get_app_configs
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.get_model

Comment: Thanks. Your answer was accurate and gives me better idea. And code works. I will probably try to change that.