# How to convert string to call model's name in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

view.py

```
from .models import Banana, Mango
list = request.GET['fruit[]']
for x in list:
    conn = x.objects.all()
    print(conn.name)
```

in html file:
I use checkbox to choose "Mango" and "Banana", and view.py get the value of checkbox. Then I want to select the model of user choices.

when I run this code, it is appear
AttributeError at /search
'str' object has no attribute 'objects'.

In that's code, I want to return name value of objects model in my models.py

How I can replace string in List to call object models in django?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django: Get model from string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4881607/django-get-model-from-string)

Answer (score 12):

If you have to load your model from a `str` value, use `django.apps.get_model()` helper

```
from django.apps import apps

Model = apps.get_model('app_name', 'model_name')
for element in Model.objects.all():
    print(element)
```

Comment: Thank you sir. Now i can load my model from a str

Answer (score 3):

Put the model classes themselves in the list ...

```
from .models import Banana, Mango

lst = [Banana, Mango]  # do not call variable 'list'
# ...
```

... and you won't have to do any string-to-model conversion at all.