# django models cyclic import

Tags: python, django, import

I have read some relevant posts on the issue on mutual imports (circular). I am working on a django app, here's how I run to an issue:

I have two apps, first one `articles`, second one `tags`

my article model have a many to many field, to indicate relevant tags:

`articles/models.py`

```py
from django.db import models
from tags.models import Tag

class Article(models.Model):
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
```

however, in my `tags` app, I also need to import `Article` model to achieve the methods:

`tags/models.py`

```py
from django.db import models
from articles.models import Article

# Create your models here.
class Tag(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def getAritcleLength():
        pass

    def getQuestionLength():
        pass
```

I usually use a module to combine those class definitions, normally won't run into issue according to method resolution order. However, in django the workflow we need to put classes into separated folders, I will be so glad for any suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't import the Tag model in the Article model, but use the string reference of the class instead.

```
# articles/models.py

from django.db import models


class Article(models.Model):
    tags = models.ManyToManyField('Tag')    OR: you can use app_name.model_name format as well
```

Another way is to use Django's method to get the model from a string and then use that variable in place for the model reference.
[Django: Get model from string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4881607/django-get-model-from-string)

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete this string

```
from articles.models import Article
```