# How to get instance from global id in Django with Graphene Relay

Tags: django, graphene-django

`graphql_relay` has a function `from_global_id` which returns the `model_name` and the `instance_id`.

However, it seems that to retrieve the model from the name of the model, we need to know in which app the model is, such as answers in the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4881607/django-get-model-from-string) asking how to get the model from its name.

Is there a way to know the name of the app from the global id? Or is there any other way to retrieve the instance?