# Django get models by model name

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

In `Django` I know that there is one and only one model with name `foo`, but I don't know the app that this model is registered with! How can I get the model with only `model_name`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the answers to [Django: Get model from string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4881607/django-get-model-from-string) show, you need either the `app_name` string or an `AppConfig` object to get a model from `model_name`.

However, you can use [`apps.get_app_configs()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/applications/#django.apps.apps.get_app_configs) to iterate over `AppConfig` instances, so something like this is possible:

```py
from django.apps import apps

for app_conf in apps.get_app_configs():
    try:
        foo_model = app_conf.get_model('foo')
        break # stop as soon as it is found
    except LookupError:
        # no such model in this application
        pass
```

Note that this iterable will include base django apps that are in `INSTALLED_APPS` like `admin`, `auth`, `contenttypes`, `sessions`, `messages` and `staticfiles`.

Answer (score 2):

1. Get all models.

```py
from django.apps import apps
apps.get_models()
```

2. Get model by app name and model_name.

```py
from django.apps import apps
apps.get_model(app_label="your_app_label", model_name="your_model_name_in_lower_case")
```

3. model can be also get by simply.

```py
from django.apps import apps
apps.get_model('app_label.model_name')
```

---

Also, To know the model_name

```py
from your_app.models import your_model
your_model._meta.model_name
```