# module 'django.apps' has no attribute 'get_model'

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am writing a function to delete object, with only by sending it's `app_name` and `model_name` in from url. Here is my function:

```
def deleteobject(request, app_name, model_name, id):
    print(app_name, model_name, id)
    print(type(app_name), type(model_name), type(id))

    try:
        model_class = apps.get_model(app_name,model_name)
    except LookupError:
        model_class = None
    print(model_class)

    if model_class:
        try:
            obj = model_class.objects.get(id=id)
            print(obj)
            obj.delete()
        except model_class.DoesNotExist:
            return HttpResponseBadRequest("Object not found.")
    else:
        return HttpResponseBadRequest("Invalid model name.")
    
    return redirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', '/'))
```

it returns this error message:

> AttributeError at /projectmanagement/delete/ProjectManagement/task/1
> module 'django.apps' has no attribute 'get_model'

Comment: Check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4881607/django-get-model-from-string